# How to grep lines with exact match

Tags: regex, macos, awk, terminal, grep

I have file with ips and port number in the below format

```
ip:port Written
ip:port Not Written
```

*example : 127.0.0.1:80 Written*

I want to grep lines which have Written only , when i tried `grep "Written" file.txt` , I got all the lines since written is present is with not written.

I also tried `grep -x "Written" file.txt` and `grep -E "Written" file.txt`

All the methods gave me the same output

OS: MAC OSx

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use this `awk` for non-regex, exact match:

```
awk '$2 == "Written"' file
```

```
127.0.0.1:80 Written
```

Using `gnu -grep` (available on OSX via `brew` installer), you can use a negative lookbehind in `-P` (PCRE option):

```
grep -P '(?<!\bNot\h)\bWritten\b' file
```